# Can we make 10k rep privilege pictures look more professional?

Tags: feature-request, privileges-page

On every SE site, on the [10k privilege description page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) in Help there are these screenshots:

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

Could we make them look a bit more professional? Or is it some kind of tradition, like the lowercase glory of possible duplicates?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775 for all the dirty details. :)

Comment: I would use "proper to each site" rather than "professional", as each site got its own, different, design.

Answer (score 7):

Not an excuse, but I would suspect that the screen shot came from an answer here on meta that explained the feature and here we **do** have a [tradition of annotating screen shots](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775) with free hand circles and arrows. If you do a search in comments (using the data explorer) you'll find numerous ones along the lines of:

> -1 Not enough free hand circles.

However, having said that, yes the screen shot in the help should be a little more professional.